# Laravel 5.4 display another button renewal if created_time is more than one year

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel and I want to pass a data to display a new button for renewal of application when the user application is already more than one year. But if the application is not more than one year it will not display the renew button. I tried using blade @if else statement in the datatable but it does not display the information when I tried to use @if else statement using blade and it says:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTableBuilder - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Here is the code in my

**datatables_actions.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['applicant.applications.destroy', $application_number], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
<div class='btn-group'>
    <a href="{{ route('applicant.applications.show', $application_number) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
    </a>
    @if ($application->created_at->gt(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addYear()))
        <a href="{{ route('applicant.applications.renew', $application_number) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
        </a>
    @endif
   <!--  <a href="{{ route('applicant.applications.edit', $application_number) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
    </a> -->
   <!--  {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', [
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs',
        'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"
    ]) !!} -->
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: If you remove the @if it works?

Comment: yes it displays the data. But I only need that button if the application created_at date is more than one year

Comment: Check if your created_at is an instance of Carbon, normally Laravel do it by default on timestamps but make sure and of course if the value is not null.

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry I am just new to laravel and using of carbon

Comment: On your controller you just can run `dd($model->created_at)`, there you can see all the information.

Comment: btw I tried to open my console and I got this error:


(2/2) ErrorException
Call to a member function addYear() on string (View: /home/jayzdevera/Documents/CrudCCTV/cctv-crud/web/resources/views/applicant-dashboard/applications/datatables_actions.blade.php)

Comment: Add in your model: `protected $dates = ['created_at'];` and try again, make sure you have the default timestamps date type in your database column.

Comment: still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `</a>` closing tag

Try with a different comparation:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['applicant.applications.destroy', $application_number], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
<div class='btn-group'>
    <a href="{{ route('applicant.applications.show', $application_number) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
    </a>
    @if ($application->created_at->diffInYears(\Carbon\Carbon::now())>=1)
        <a href="{{ route('applicant.applications.renew', $application_number) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"></a>
        </a>
    @endif
   <!--  <a href="{{ route('applicant.applications.edit', $application_number) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
    </a> -->
   <!--  {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', [
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs',
        'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"
    ]) !!} -->
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: This kind of errors from dataTable builder use to be syntax html errors @Idan